# What is causing error about unexpected token in json

Tags: .net, maui

I have a class called operation in my MAUI app and I create an instance of it in the first line of referred code.

Then I serialize it with NewtonSoft.Json nuget library and finally try to post it to my .NET6 Rest API on localhost. But execution never goes to backend brake point.
Error is unexpected token in json input.
Im I doing something wrong in below code? Get requests and deserializing works fine but
post doesn´t:

'''

```
Operation op = new Operation();
            op.EmployeeID = eId;
            op.WorkAssignmentID = wa.IdWorkAssignment;
            op.CustomerID = wa.IdCustomer;
            op.OperationType = "start";
            op.Comment = "Aloitettu";
            op.Latitude = lat;
            op.Longitude = lon;
            

#if DEBUG
            HttpsClientHandlerService handler = new HttpsClientHandlerService();
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler.GetPlatformMessageHandler());
#else
                    client = new HttpClient();
#endif
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ApiBaseUrl);

            var input = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(op);

            HttpContent content = new StringContent(input, Encoding.UTF8,"application/json");

            HttpResponseMessage message = await client.PostAsync("/api/workassignments", content);
```

'''

Comment: please post the **exact** exception type and message

Comment: JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. path " , line 1, position 1.

Comment: the exception is thrown by `PostAsync`?  What does the stack trace show?

Comment: Now I found the reason when I DisplayAlerted the response. Latitude and Longitude are nulls and Backend is reacting to that. Actually the problem in maui app was when it tried to parse the responce json!! :) ..and not the request data as I tought. Res should be boolean.

Comment: Please edit the question to match  what you’ve said in your comments. It’s getting confusing to understand.